# Linked List, inserting a node in the front

Tags: c, linked-list

Given an object that holds a linked list, how can I add a new node to the head of that linked list, when I can't return the memory address of that linked list?

```
struct group {
    char *name;
    struct user *users;
    struct xct *xcts;
    struct group *next;
};

struct user {
    char *name;
    double balance;
    struct user *next;
};
```

Comment: `usr->name = user_name;` should be `strcpy(usr->name,user_name);` No? Also, `usr->name` should be allocated some memory? You are making an **shallow copy** of node contents you need a **deep copy**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler than what you think:

```
usr->next = group->users;
group->users = usr;
```